# Bash - non-numeral arguments to [] operator(array)

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I have a small script below; however, I don't quite understand the for loop and if statement. First, let's take a look at script:

```
listFieldNumbers ()
 { for ii in ${!field_number[@]}; 
do 
if [ $ii -lt $(( ${#field_number[*]}-1 )) ];
 then echo -n "$(( ${field_number[$ii]} + 1 )),"; 
else echo "$(( ${field_number[$ii]} + 1))"; 
fi; 
done; }
```

I don't understand what do following statements mean:

1. `field_number[@]`
2. `{#field_number[*]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`field_number` is an array
`${!field_number[@]}` gives you the list of indices of the array
`${#field_number[*]}` is the number of elements in the array.

I'd recommend you look for a bash tutorial about arrays. They are a bit tricky to work with.

Answer (score 1):

1. reference all the element in the field_number array
2. it's `${#field_number[*]}`, the number of field_number elements

Just read this tutorial: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/